# Entity Framework retornar qualquer tipo de dado com SqlQuery

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

Estou tentando retornar valores dinamicos de uma query também dinamica, porém não consigo descobrir como pegar qualquer tipo de dados do banco.

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte

```
comandoSql = @" SELECT " + NomeCampo + " FROM " + Tabela + " WHERE Id = @p0";
var result = _db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(comandoSql, id).ToList();
```

Dá certo quando meu retorno é um campo varchar. Porém como a query é dinamica, eu posso querer consultar outros campos de outras tabelas, então se vier um numeric, datetime etc retorna um erro.

Já tentei utilizar SqlQuery e SqlQuery mas não consigo obter o valor de dentro do objeto depois.

Comment: Já tentou usar o Dapper? Ele vai fazer exatamente o que quer e é muito mais leve que o EF.

Comment: com dapper eu consigo, porém para essa solução não posso utilizar dapper por algumas questões internas.

Comment: Porque não tenta utilizar o contexto do EF? Você chama a classe de contexto do banco e cria objetos que dão acesso a tabela. Isso resolveria?

Comment: Utilizar o `dynamic` não resolve? `_db.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(comandoSql, id)`; Depois só teria que tratar a informação que ele devolve.

Comment: então, tentei usar dynamic, mas não consigo tratar a informação quando retorna.O valor da informação fica como {object} apenas.

Comment: Mas desse `object` não consegue tirar o tipo? `object.GetType()`?

Comment: não consigo fazer nada com esse objeto. não tem nenhuma funcao ou propiedade depois que retorna.

Comment: Resolvido pelo dapper mesmo, utilizando retorno dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

Porque não utilizar uma lista genérica (*código não testado*)?

```
public static List<T> GetQuery<T>(string NomeCampo, string Tabela, int id) where T : class
{
    comandoSql = $" SELECT {NomeCampo} FROM {Tabela} WHERE Id = @p0";
    return _db.Database.SqlQuery<T>(comandoSql, id).ToList();
}
```

A utilização seria:

```
List<string> lista = GetQuery<string>("Nome", "Clientes", 10);
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. mas cai no mesmo caso que tinha explicado. eu preciso passar o tipo de dado para esse metodo para funcionar, o problema é que não tenho o tipo de dado que vai vir de cada campo passado na query.

Comment: Não tendo essa informação fica difícil! Não existe forma de saber o tipo?

Comment: é isso que eu queria saber. se existe uma forma de pegar o campo independente do tipo. mas eu fiz com dapper mesmo, com tipo dynamic.